# std::is_sorted and strictly less comparison?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, comparator, stl-algorithm

I do not understand well the `std::is_sorted` algorithm and its default behaviour. If we look to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted), it says that by default `std::is_sorted` uses the `<` operator. Instead of that, I find that using `<=` would be natural. But my problem is that for the following list of numbers :

```
1 2 3 3 4 5
```

it will return `true`, even if `3 < 3` should be `false`. How is that possible ?

EDIT: its seems to be worse than what I thought, because passing `std::less_equal<int>` will return false in that case... What is the condition applied when I pass a comparator function?

Comment: [Effective STL](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Specific-Standard-Template/dp/0201749629) by Scott Meyers, Item 19: "Understand the difference between equivalence and equality"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per 25.4/5:

> A sequence is sorted with respect to a comparator `comp` if for any
>   iterator `i` pointing to the sequence and any non-negative integer `n`
>   such that `i + n` is a valid iterator pointing to an element of the
>   sequence, **`comp(*(i + n), *i) == false`**.

So, for

```
1 2 3 3 4 5
```

`std::less<int>()(*(i + n), *i)` will return `false` for all `n`, while `std::less_equal` will return `true` for case `3 3`.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense now, even if it is counter-intuitive for me.

Comment: @Vincent, It was counter intuitive for me too until I looked in the Standard :)

Comment: i feel like if I had a standard quote in all my answers my rep would be way higher

Comment: @aaronman When the standard is as clear as this, I think there is no better answer than that.

Comment: @Vincent I would just like to point out that paxdiablos answer had this first, I edited mine after, he was saying the same thing without a standards quote

Comment: @aaronman, The point is: only the Standard determines the behavior in all cases.

Comment: my only point is that @Vincent argued that behavior that paxdiablo  and I assumed it was using was not how it was behaving, but when he sees it in the standard he automatically agrees with it

Answer (score 4):

Even if you only have the `<` operator you can figure out if two numbers are equivalent not necessarily equal.

`if !(first < second) and !(second < first)

then first equivalent to second`

In addition, as paxdiablo's solution actually  mentioned first, you could implement `is_sorted` as going up the list and continually checking for `<` not to be true, if it is ever true you stop.

Here is the correct behavior of the function from cplusplus.com

```
template <class ForwardIterator>
  bool is_sorted (ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last)
{
  if (first==last) return true;
  ForwardIterator next = first;
  while (++next!=last) {
    if (*next<*first)     // or, if (comp(*next,*first)) for version (2)
      return false;
    ++first;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: I know that, but I think that `std::is_sorted` would return `true` if the provided condition was `true` for all `(N, N+1)` element and that is not the case.

Comment: @Vincent not following could you elaborate

Comment: if I pass the comparator `std::less<int>`, the comparison will return : `true` for `(1, 2)`, `true` for `(2, 3)` but `false` for `(3, 3)`, so I thought that the algorithm stops here (first `false` detected) and return `false`. But that's not the case.

Comment: [Effective STL](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-STL-Specific-Standard-Template/dp/0201749629) by Scott Meyers, Item 19: "Understand the difference between equivalence and equality" In particular `!(a < b) && !(b < a)` does not mean `a == b` but only that `a` and `b` are [equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). For builtin types these notions coincide but not necessarily for class types. Equivalence is useful for partitioning (e.g. the `std::multiset` container and `std::partition` algorithm)

Comment: @TemplateRex So what does that imply, just that the two objects are not necessarily exactly the same but just a equivalent

Comment: consider a class with 2 strings, first and last name. if you sort by last name only, then equivalence means 2 objects have equal last names, and equality means that they are equal on first name as well.

Comment: @TemplateRex yeah thats how i understand it, its a bit nit picky then who would assume that made 2 objects exactly the same

Comment: The subtle difference between equality and equivalence is the difference between e.g. `stable_sort` and `sort`. It is not nitpicking at all (unless you consider Scott Meyers to write [nitpicking books](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/819272))! I have to downvote your answer as it stands, but if you change it to reflect these concepts, I would upvote it.

Comment: @templaterex edited, just to be clear i understood your point

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be assuming that it's checking (for the positive case) if element N is less than element N+1 for all elements bar the last. That would indeed not work with just `<`, though you can use a 'trick' to evaluate `<=` with `<` and `!`: the following two are equivalent:

```
if (a <= b)
if ((a < b) || (!((b < a) || (a < b)))) // no attempt at simplification.
```

However, it's far more likely that it detects (the negative case) if element N is less than element N-1 for all but the first so that it can stop as soon as it finds a violation. That *can* be done with nothing more than `<`, something like (pseudocode):

```
for i = 1 to len - 1:
    if elem[i] < elem[i-1]:
        return false
return true
```