# std::is_sorted and the comparator requirement misleading?

Tags: c++, std

I came across the old question on is_sorted here: [std::is_sorted and strictly less comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769114/stdis-sorted-and-strictly-less-comparison)

after stumbling upon a use case where monotonicity check using a comparator of pairs failed the tests. I thought giving the lambda as below was in line with the requirements: it would return true (only if) both elements of lhs and rhs were sorted

```
bool 
check_pair_sorted(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& vec)
{
    return std::is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end(),[](auto& lhs, auto& rhs){
            return (lhs.first < rhs.first) && (lhs.second < rhs.second);
            });
}
```

However, the true intended function is possible if I split the check like so

```
bool check_separate_sorted(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>& vec)
{
    return std::is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end(),[](auto& lhs, auto& rhs){
           return (lhs.first < rhs.first) ; })
        && std::is_sorted(vec.begin(), vec.end(),[](auto& lhs, auto& rhs){ 
           return (lhs.second < rhs.second) ; });
}
```

Looking at the answers in the questions above, where it is suggested an early-return of false might be the preferred implementation, shouldn't the requirement also be posed likewise?

> comp  -   comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns **false** if the first argument is **not** less than (i.e. is **not** ordered before) the second.

It's possible that I might be missing something in terms of ordering here, but just can't seem to wrap my head around it at the moment.

Comment: There's a good use for [`std::tie`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) in element-wise comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Your `check_pair_sorted` is doing a different thing than `check_separate_sorted` and that is, I presume, the source of confusion.

It comes down to the precise wording of how `std::is_sorted` is defined. For every two elements `a[i]` and `a[j]` where `i`<`j`:

- it checks that `a[j] < a[i]` is never true
- it does *not* check that `a[i] < a[j]` is always true

(naturally, a clever algorithm avoids making all O(n^2) comparisons)

Those two bullets above are not the same!

For simple numbers, as in the other SO question, sequence `1 2 3 3 4 5` satisfies the first point, but it does not satisfy the latter.

Something similar happens in your case. Consider a sequence of two pairs: `{ {1,2}, {2,1} }`. The elements of the sequence are different, but they are not comparable by your first lambda comparator - it returns `false` in both directions. So, for the purpose of the algorithm, those two elements are treated as *equivalent*, even if they are not strictly equal.

So, `is_sorted` inside your `check_pair_sorted` for the sequence `{ {1,2}, {2,1} }` *will* return `true`, as it checks the first bullet point and not the second.

Note, that the same equivalency issue can affect other STL structures and algorithms. For example, if you have a `std::set`, you would not be able to have both `{1,2}` and `{2,1}` elements in it using your first lambda as a comparator.

Comment: I actually figured out from the answer by paxdiablo in the linked SO question. That is_sorted is actually checking that a[j] is not less a[i] for consecutive i,j. Shouldn't the standard in that case better require a comparator that does that?

My main query was that the comparator definition seems to be somehow misleading (at least I got mislead, which I addressed thanks to the tests). Shouldn't it be defined so it reflects the first bullet point and not the second?

Comment: To my knowledge, all STL uses a single kind of comparator. Introducing another one which would basically be a negation of the former seems redundant. Moreover, naming it `operator>=` (or similar) could be even more misleading, as it should read "greater-equal-or-noncomparable".

Answer (score 1):

For lexical sorting you need:

```
return (lhs.first < rhs.first) || ((lhs.first == rhs.first) && lhs.second < rhs.second));
```

Comment: *Why?* Can you please add an explanation of why that is needed for lexical sorting.

Comment: I  kind of get what you mean here, but interestingly, one test still fails for me: cpp.sh/4o3g7

Comment: Your third test checks that all `lhs.first`s are less then all `rhs.first`s and that all `lhs.second`s are less than all `rhs.second`s which is clearly not the case in the `nmis` vector you test.  You probably meant to test the `mib` vector.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, mib (monotonic in both) is definitely what should pass and does even with my comparator without lexical checks. I expect both other vectors nmif and nmis (non-monotonic in first/second) to fail, i.e. return 0 (which would be a test pass)  and it happens only for the _separate_ comparator. Considering the logical || I'd expect the _lexical_ to work as the _separate_ but it doesn't in the non-monotonic in second (nmis) vector

Comment: I'm not sure I followed. Can you change all tests to display `true` when they pass? [cpp.sh/33gkq](http://cpp.sh/33gkq)

Comment: @TedLyngmo, Here you go cpp.sh/75fay. I tried to make it verbose enough. Also I added a level of complication to the story with a version of the comparator that worked as I'd like. Of course I still feel that the comparator requirement doesn't reflect what the algorithm tries to achieve. Or al least, it's not very explicit.

Comment: @AseemDua I'm not sure I understand it either, but I added some debug prints that might help: [cpp.sh/9u4bn](http://cpp.sh/9u4bn). The last test should return true and not false though.

Answer (score 1):

[std::is_sorted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/is_sorted) is clearly defined in terms of comparison function - operator<() or some functional object - lambda in TS`s example.

However, if the comparison function is constructed in such a way, that 2 elements don't have clear relation - i.e. both **a < b** and **b < a** are **true** - then the result of *any* sorting or ordering operation can not be fully defined.

This is the real source of confusion.

Comment: I think another way to put it is that the Comparator must obey a _strict total ordering_ which means that for all distinct a,b, either a<b or b<a hold. Also called Connexity.

In my case both a<b and b<a cannot be true together, however they can be false together. For example,

(10, 50) < (20, 20) is false as 50<20 is false. Also,
(20, 20) < (10, 50) is false as 20<10 is false.

Comment: Well, but if a<b and b<a are both false, then this implies that a>=b and b>=a true, which in turn means that elements are equivalent (a == b).